# Rotating Box3 together with the model in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I have the following question.

There is a model, through the setFromObject method I get Box3 (screenshot - http://prntscr.com/12787py). Next, I rotate the model and get a new Box3 (screenshot - http://prntscr.com/12789fy).

Is it possible after rotating the model to get Box3 with the same rotation, as if Box3 was rotating with the model?

Answer (score 1):

[`Box3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3) is a mathematical representation of a box. As such, it is represented with only two `Vector3` properties (`max` and `min`) that represent two opposing corners of the box. The values of these do not represent a box in full 3D space, but rather an axis-aligned box.

It looks like you're using [`BoundingBoxHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=helper#api/en/helpers/BoxHelper). This creates a wireframe box that is world-aligned. This means it will compute its shape based on the *transformed* positions of the geometry vertices, and so it may change shape as your mesh is rotated.

To create a shape-tight wireframe box that rotates with your object, you will need to create one directly from your geometry, and ensure the same transformation is applied to both shapes.

```js
// your shape
const shapeGeo = new BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 )
shapeGeo.computeBoundingBox() // <----------- DO THIS BEFORE ADDING IT TO THE SCENE!
const shapeMat = new MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 'red' } )
const shapeMsh = new Mesh( shapeGeo, shapeMat )

// your wireframe
const bboxMin = shapeGeo.boundingBox.min
const bboxMax = shapeGeo.boundingBox.max
const wireGeo = new BufferGeometry()
wireGeo.setAttribute( 'position' , new BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( [
  bboxMin.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMin.z,
  bboxMin.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMax.z,
  bboxMin.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z,
  bboxMin.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMin.z,
  bboxMax.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMin.z,
  bboxMax.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMax.z,
  bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z,
  bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMin.z,
] ), 3, false ) )
wireGeo.setIndex( new BufferAttribute( new Uint8Array( [
  0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0,
  4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4,
  0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7
] ), 1, false ) )
const wireMat = new LineBasicMaterial( { color: 'yellow' } )
const wireBox = new LineSegments( wireGeo, wireMat )
```

Now, here's where things take what might seem like an odd twist. Once you have your wire box, you can simply add it to your shape, and future changes to your shape will be passed on to your wire box:

```js
scene.add( shapeMsh )
shapeMsh.add( wireBox )
```

This works because transformations are passed on to children*, and a `Mesh` is really just an extension of `Object3D`, so a `Mesh` can have children just like any other `Object3D` derivative.

* *as long as you don't disable automatic matrix updates*

Comment: Thanks for detail answer, but unfortunately I wanted to use Box3 for detection collisions like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection/Bounding_volume_collision_detection_with_THREE.js

Comment: @Алексей You should have included that in your question. Regardless, `Box3.intersectsBox` expects both boxes to be occupying the same coordinate system (have the same alignment).

Comment: Yes, I had to include this staff, sorry. Do you have any idea how to solve my task? Thanks for help.